# How develop PostgreSQL extension inluding PostGIS library

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile, postgis

I'm NOT a C expert.
That been said building PostgreSQL extension using or not C is very powerful.

99% of the time I work also using PostGIS, and extensions too, but here is the problem:
Cannot properly include what is needed, I've played using

```
#include "../postgis_config.h"
#include "liblwgeom.h"
#include "lwgeom_pg.h"
```

but cannot have a proper result without recompiling whole PostGIS... and so create a derived version.

PostGIS should be dependency for the lib I've in mind, so I need something that link to it, if present or catch error, while compiling my lib...

Currently I'm resolving using the PostgreSQL's `#include <utils/geo_decls.h>`
so creating PostgreSQL functions interfaces that:

1. translates a PostGIS feature to a PostgreSQL base geo type
2. pass the results to my C libs
3. works with those very base types (loosing any support from powerful PostGIS lib )
4. send result to the function that translate back to PostGIS.

Just go give a simple idea of what I'm doing now:
*mylib.c*

```
#include "postgres.h"           
#include "fmgr.h"
#include <utils/geo_decls.h>    
#include "utils/builtins.h"

Datum pg_xytile_to_box(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int x, y, zoom;
    struct tile_box box;
    BOX *pg_box = (BOX *) palloc(sizeof(BOX));

    x = PG_GETARG_INT64(0);
    y = PG_GETARG_INT64(1);
    zoom = PG_GETARG_INT32(2);

    if ( xytile_to_box(&box, x, y, zoom) != 0 )
    {
        pfree(pg_box);
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }

    pg_box->low.x = box.w;
    pg_box->low.y = box.s;
    pg_box->high.x = box.e;
    pg_box->high.y = box.n;

    PG_RETURN_BOX_P(pg_box);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pg_xytile_to_box);
```

*extension_code.sql*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _xytile_to_box(x int, y int, zoom int default 11) RETURNS box
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'pg_xytile_to_box'
 LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xtile_to_geom(xtile int, ytile int, zoom int default 11) returns geometry(polygon, 4326)
language plpgsql security definer as $FUNC$
BEGIN
return (
select st_setsrid((ST_MakeBox2D(b[0]::geometry(point), b[1]::geometry(point)))::geometry(polygon), 4326) as t
from _xytile_to_box(xtile, ytile, zoom) as b
);
END; $FUNC$;
```

There is a way to instruct a Makefile to find and add PostGIS to the imports?
There is something better?

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS doesn't seem to have a public C API, so you won't be able to link to the PostGIS libraries directly.

My recommendation is to call the PostGIS SQL functions from your C code by using the [Server Programming Interface (SPI)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html). An alternative is calling PostGIS functions directly with the function-call interface in `include/fmgr.h`, which would be faster, but requires that you first look up the functions in the catalog.